# Finding change on unknown commit in Git

Tags: git

I know I made a particular change to a file but I can no longer find it.  I tried using these commands:

```
git log -SINSTALLED ./features/test-cases/upgrade.feature
git log -SINSTALLED ^HEAD ./features/test-cases/upgrade.feature
```

This is not currently finding anything probably because the change is not in an ancestor of my current branch and the branch appears to have been deleted.  Is there a way to search all commits?

Comment: Is it the case that the branch was never merged into anything else?

Comment: As with all `git log` commands, it will search backwards from `HEAD` by default, but from all the starting points you give it if you give it starting points: `--all` means "all references"; `--branches` means "all branches" (a subset of `--all`).

Comment: Yes, this branch was never merged.

Comment: In fact, the branch name was deleted.  I found the commit using `git reflog` but I would prefer a method that's more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In fact, the branch name was deleted. I found the commit using git reflog but I would prefer a method that's more reliable

Then adding [`--reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---reflog) should be enough:

```
git log -SINSTALLED --reflog
```